# Error 1053 for Windows Service appears before timeout reached

Tags: c#, windows-services

I created a service in C# on my machine then installed it on to a server through Remote Desktop. When I try to start the service, the dialog box with the *1053 Error* appears in less than a second. I can install and run the service on my own desktop fine. I have started this service on the same server before, but now it doesn't work, and the timeout is clearly not being reached.

Comment: What are the differences from the Server Paths vs The Paths on your Local Machine, check out the config file as well It's probably something simple also check to see what the Permissions are for that Service is there a Service Account setup on that remote server..?

Comment: have you checked this support link from MS for the error http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839174

Comment: I figured out why this was. The target framework in my project was pointed at .NET 4.0 whereas the previous versions were pointed at .NET 4.0 Client Profile. I downloaded .NET 4 on the server and it worked fine.

Comment: FYI 1053 = `0x0000041D` = `ERROR_SERVICE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT` "The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."